# Error consuming a WCF service in a windows service

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, windows-services, proxy-classes

I have a WCF service which is consumed by multiple applications. I am able to consume the WCF service in a Silverlight application. But when I try to consume the WCF service in a windows service application, it does not work.

Specifically, the error I am getting in `Reference.cs`<sup>†</sup> is:

> The type name 'ServiceReference1' does not exist in the type 'xxx.xxx'.

I received this error after using the tool in Visual Studio<sup>†</sup> to add a service reference to this WCF service and then attempting build the windows service project. Can anyone help?

---

<sup>†</sup> Assumptions made by editor.

Comment: what is the error you get? Post the service and client configs as well

Comment: Make sure that your windows service can read the application configuration file. The default working directory for windows services is C:\Windows\System32, regardless where the executable is located.

Comment: I believe that the problem described here might be addressed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33617608/1497596).